# Current driven proportional solenoid EMC

Tags: dc-dc-converter, solenoid-valve

I'm looking to control a solenoid like this one through up to 60 feet of cable. [(PV3P12032A0)](https://www.humphrey-products.com/products/small-2-port-proportional-solenoid-valves-flow/PV3P12032A0-flow)

[image: PV3P12032A0]

One chip I've looked at is the [infineon TLE82453](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-TLE82453-3SA-DS-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4624cb7f111014d289949d61dff), although there are quite a few of this type from different sources.

While essentially using the coil as part of a dc/dc converter makes sense, what are the EMC implications of doing this, especially through long cables?

Comment: You should edit your question to include that this is a **'proportional'** solenoid (0-200mA, 50 Ohms, 2 W input).  I bit different than what we normally see here.

Comment: Why is the coil (solenoid?) part of a dc to dc converter?

Comment: Because the driver is using the solenoid coil to ramp up/down very similar to the way a dc converter would be driven.  It is a way to proportionally drive the coil without linear losses.

Comment: If EMC is a concern, I would consider driving it with a voltage or current source. That should be fairly quiet if you design it well.

Comment: Linear is a valid way, but in this case it would dissipate 1.96W@7V per channel assuming 25R load per datasheet and 14V input.

Comment: If your cable has a good shield that is connected to the chassis on both ends, that makes a pretty nice faraday cage for the drive currents.

Comment: That's a very nice automotive driver. Automotive might let them get away with EMC stuff you wouldn't in other classes of equipment. On the other hand, because it's current controlled and your load is inductive anyway, and typically low kHz electromechanical corner freq, there's plenty of room between the switching noise frequency and frequency of interest in the load, to filter it

Comment: Probably better to think of this not as a DC/DC, but as a voltage-PWM, hysteresis-controlled, current controlled solenoid driver -- with the value added feature of a low frequency dither waveform superimposed on the current set point signal (useful in the end application) ... for EMC purposes it's just a PWM driver.